Why would one use the [[indeterminate]] attribute?
The description of the [[indeterminate]] attribute, and the examples given on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/indeterminate are clear in the definition, but don't suggest any practical usage. When would a developer opt to use [[indeterminate]]? What is a practical example where this attribute will be helpful?

The example tell you the case: just restoring the old behaviour. Useful: probably never. In past it was used to get some randomness (e.g. to seed random numbers, just slightly better then a constant). Maybe to teach about stack overflow and such things (to student), possibly for introspection/debugger. I think it is not for 99.99% of us
